# How does the Adobe AIR packager for Android work?

Tags: android, air, llvm

I know that Adobe's packager for iOS uses LLVM compiler to produce native code.  Is this how the Android packager works?

Is the Adobe AIR "runtime" that you install on Android really a runtime engine?

Does it interpret ActionScript ByteCode - like in the browser plug-in - or is just it a library of classes and methods?  Called by your AIR app?

For comparison, what are the differences between the way Adobe ActionScript, and Corona LUA are packaged for mobile devices?

Answer (score 0):

ActionScripts are designed to target an ActionScript Virtual Machine (AVM) for portability.

However, in iOS, Adobe doesn't have a choice as Apple specifically says no interpreted code should be run on it.  Interpreting the actionscript bytecode in an AVM would violate Apple's policy.  To go around this, Adobe has to convert the actionscript code into Objective-C equivalence to run on iOS.

There's no such restriction imposed by Google for Android, hence Adobe should still be using an AVM to execute AIR's code.  Basically, the AVM implementation and AIR runtime is likely to be written in native Android code, which gives it speed and autonomy over a plug-in implementation in a web browser.

Would be great if someone who knows more about this topic cares to share.  Thanks.